# converting a Tensorflow model for Tensorflow.js

Tags: tensorflow

(Warning, I'm a Tensorflow/ML noob)

I'm trying to convert and load a TensorFlow model into tensorflow.js

The model is [saved](https://github.com/HadoopIt/rnn-nlu/blob/master/run_multi-task_rnn.py#L338):

```
saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step=model.global_step)
```

and potentially [restored](https://github.com/HadoopIt/rnn-nlu/blob/master/run_multi-task_rnn.py#L221):

```
saver.restore(session, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
```

This (and similar lines) creates a directory structure:

```
model_tmp
  checkpoint
  model.ckpt-100.data-00000-of-00001
  model.ckpt-100.index
  model.ckpt-100.meta
  ...
  model.ckpt-500.meta
```

...So I should be able to [convert](https://github.com/OpenASR/rnn-nlu/blob/master/scripts/convert) to a JS model, right?

```
#TODO --output_node_names='???' \
tensorflowjs_converter \
    --input_format=tf_saved_model \
    --saved_model_tags=serve \
    model_tmp/model.ckpt-500 \
    model_web
```

Wrong! When I run the script above I get an error:

```
IOError: SavedModel file does not exist at: model_tmp/model.ckpt-500
```

I've tried `model_tmp`, `model_tmp/checkpoint` but neither of them work either.

Also, I'm not sure what to provide at [`output_node_names`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter) in the converter call.

Answer (score 1):

You can build from source and use the `summarize_graph` tool which is distributed as a part of Tensorflow `graph_transforms` tools. Detailed docs are available [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md). Quick install:

First, make sure you have `bazel` build system installed (for MacOS):

```
brew install bazel
```

Next get Tensorflow sources, build and run `summarize_graph`:

```
git clone git@github.com:tensorflow/tensorflow.git
cd tensorflow
bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph --in_graph=path/to/model_graphdef.pb
```

Note that `summarize_graph` requires GraphDef format as input.

If during the build attempt bazel can't find Xcode, configure it:

```
bazel clean --expunge 
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -license
bazel clean --expunge
```

Answer (score 0):

tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph OR /tools/benchmark:benchmark_model will show the input and outpt node names

Comment: Can you be more explicit in your answer?  This is pretty terse.