# Tensorflow.js mapping to Tensorflow (python)

Tags: tensorflow

Despite having no understanding of what I'm doing, I decided to take a shot at porting [rnn-nlu](https://github.com/HadoopIt/rnn-nlu) to tensorflow.js

A few lines in, and I'm really confused by the relationship between the python and javascript APIs.

Take the following code:

```
def create_cell():
  if not forward_only and dropout_keep_prob < 1.0:
    single_cell = lambda: BasicLSTMCell(self.cell_size)
    cell = MultiRNNCell([single_cell() for _ in range(self.num_layers)])
    cell = DropoutWrapper(cell,
                            input_keep_prob=dropout_keep_prob,
                            output_keep_prob=dropout_keep_prob)         
  else:
    single_cell = lambda: BasicLSTMCell(self.cell_size)
    cell = MultiRNNCell([single_cell() for _ in range(self.num_layers)])
  return cell
```

For [BasicLSTMCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/BasicLSTMCell) there seem to be two very similar functions in the tensorflow-js:

- [tf.basicLSTMCell](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#basicLSTMCell) - identical in name, but needs `forgetBias`, `lstmKernel` and `lstmBias` which are all absent from the python call.
- [tf.layers.lstmCell](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#layers.lstmCell) - I can create one of these in a similar fashion as per the python API: `tf.layers.lstmCell({units: this.cell_size}`

The first option *seems* like a more likely candidate, but there are 3 extra parameters. If I could get past that, I could call `tf.multiRNNCell(cells)` - but that also requires `data`, `c` and `h` which are not required in the python API (which optionally takes `state` and `scope`).

If I go with the second option, it seems as though I would replace `MultiRNNCell` with `let cell =`[`tf.layers.stackedRNNCells({cells})`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#layers.stackedRNNCells) - but the difference in function names is not encouraging.

The only thing in the js API that looks remotely similar to [DropoutWrapper](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/DropoutWrapper) is [`tf.layers.dropout()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#layers.dropout) but it returns a Layer instead of a Cell and the parameters do not match at all.

I have also attempted to import a model which was learned by Python into JavaScript, but [I could not figure out how to do that either](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/36346/converting-a-tensorflow-model-for-tensorflow-js).